# WPF 4.6 and Powershell - Replacing items in a ComboBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, powershell, combobox

I'm trying to replace values in a ComboBox but I always get an error when trying to clear the Items.
I'm using the WPF from .Net Framework 4.6.

Here's the code (I'm starting using PowerShell, so it can be fuzzy) :

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[xml]$XAMLMainWindow = @'
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="Folder rights" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="247*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="545*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TreeView Name="tvFolders" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="520" Margin="10,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtFolder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="216,32,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="554" FontSize="13.333" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label Name="lblFolder" Content="Folder :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="216,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="13.333" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Button Name="btnSearch" Content="Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="462,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="61" FontSize="13.333" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Name="btnExit" Content="Exit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="462,529,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="61" FontSize="13.333" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <ListBox Name="lbReadWrite" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="396" Margin="216,128,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="272" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <ListBox Name="lbRead" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="396" Margin="268,128,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="255" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Name="lblReadWrtie" Content="Read/Write :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="216,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="13.333" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Label Name="lblRead" Content="Read :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="268,67,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="13.333" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Name="btnExport" Content="Export" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="395,529,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="61" FontSize="13.333" Height="23" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Name="lblTree" Content="Tree :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="13.333"/>
        <ComboBox Name="cbxReadWrite" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="216,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="272"/>
        <ComboBox Name="cbxRead" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="270,96,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="253"/>
        <Label Name="lblError" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="216,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" RenderTransformOrigin="0.167,0.641" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="9.333" Foreground="Red"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
'@

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

#Read XAML
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $XAMLMainWindow) 
$formMainWindow=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

# Store Form Objects In PowerShell
$XAMLMainWindow.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $formMainWindow.FindName($_.Name)}

#===============================================================================
# Add events to Form Objects
#===============================================================================

$btnExit.Add_Click({$formMainWindow.Close()})

$btnSearch.Add_Click({retrieveData;})

$cbxReadWrite.Add_SelectionChanged({populateCList;})

$cbxRead.Add_SelectionChanged({populateRList;})

#===============================================================================
# Functions
#===============================================================================

Function retrieveData()
{

    # get folder object
    try {
        # initialization
        $lblError.Content = "";
        $global:allRGroups = @();
        $global:allRUsers = @();
        $global:allCGroups = @();
        $global:allCUsers = @();

        $folder = Get-Item -Path $txtFolder.Text.ToString() -ErrorAction Continue

        # get "Read" groups
        $Raccess = (Get-Acl $folder).Access | 
            Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -like 'D1*_R'} | 
            Select-Object @{n='GroupName';e={(($_.IdentityReference).ToString()).Substring(3)}} |
            Sort-Object GroupName
        If ($Raccess) {
            foreach($access in $Raccess)
            {
                $global:allUsers = @()
                $global:allGroups = @()
                getGroupMembers($access.GroupName)
                $global:allRGroups += $global:allGroups
                $global:allRUsers += $global:allUsers
            }
        }

        # get "Read/Write" groups
        $Caccess = (Get-Acl $folder).Access | 
            Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -like 'D1*_C'} | 
            Select-Object @{n='GroupName';e={(($_.IdentityReference).ToString()).Substring(3)}}
            Sort-Object GroupName
        If ($Caccess) {
            foreach($access in $Caccess)
            {
                $global:allUsers = @()
                $global:allGroups = @()
                getGroupMembers($access.GroupName)
                $global:allCGroups += $global:allGroups
                $global:allCUsers += $global:allUsers
            }
        }  
        $cbxRead.Items.Clear();
        $cbxReadWrite.Items.Clear();
        populateCombos;
        $cbxRead.SelectedIndex = 0 ;
        $cbxReadWrite.SelectedIndex = 0;   
    } catch {
        $lblError.Content = "Erreur"
    }
}

Function populateCombos()
{
    if ($Global:allRGroups) {
        $cbxRead.Items.Add("<All>")
        $groupsToAdd = $Global:allRGroups | Sort-Object
        foreach ($group in $groupsToAdd) {            
            $cbxRead.items.add($group)            
        }
    } 
    if ($Global:allCGroups) {
        $cbxReadWrite.Items.Add("<All>")
        $groupsToAdd = $Global:allCGroups | Sort-Object
        foreach ($group in $groupsToAdd) {            
            $cbxReadWrite.items.add($group)            
        }
    } 
}

Function getGroupMembers([String]$groupToScan) 
{
    $users = Get-ADGroupMember $groupToScan | 
        Where-Object {($_.objectClass -eq 'user') -and ($_.distinguishedName -like '*MYUSERS*')}
    if ($users) {
        $global:allUsers += $users
        $global:allGroups += $groupToScan
    }
    $groups = Get-ADGroupMember $groupToScan | 
        Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq 'group'}
    if ($groups) {
        foreach($group in $groups)
        {
            getGroupMembers($group.name)
        }
    }

}

Function populateCList()
{
    ($lbReadWrite.Items).Clear()
    $selection = $cbxReadWrite.SelectedValue
    if ($selection -ne '<All>')
    {
        $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $selection -Recursive |
            Where-Object {$_.distinguishedName -like '*MYUSERS*'}
    } else {
        $members = $Global:allCUsers
    }
    if ($members) 
    {
        $membersToDsiplay = $members | 
            Select-Object @{n='DisplayName';e={$_.name + " (" + $_.SamAccountName + ")"}} |
            Sort-Object DisplayName | 
            Select -Unique DisplayName
        foreach ($member in $membersToDsiplay) 
        {
            $lbReadWrite.AddText($member.DisplayName)
        }
    }
}

Function populateRList()
{
    ($lbRead.Items).Clear()
    $selection = $cbxRead.SelectedValue
    if ($selection -ne '<All>')
    {
        $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $selection -Recursive |
            Where-Object {$_.distinguishedName -like '*MYUSERS*'} 
    } else {
        $members = $Global:allRUsers
    }
    if ($members) 
    {
        $membersToDsiplay = $members | 
            Select-Object @{n='DisplayName';e={$_.name + " (" + $_.SamAccountName + ")"}} | 
            Sort-Object DisplayName | 
            Select -Unique DisplayName
        foreach ($member in $membersToDsiplay) 
        {
            $lbRead.AddText($member.DisplayName)
        }
    }
}

#===============================================================================

# Shows the form
$formMainWindow.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

What I'm trying to do is to fill the ComboBox based an another value.
The problem is when I try to clear the control to replace the items in it, it gives me an error. The first time it goes through, $cbxRead.Items is empty and it works. The second time, it contains a System.String object which is in fact an array of String. The Clear() method gives this :

```
Exception calling "Clear" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try 
the command again."
At D:\WorkingDir\PS\fa.ps1:106 char:9
+         ($cbxRead.Items).Clear();
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingValidationException
```

What is stange is : if I put a breakpoint on the faulty command, and I type it manually in the command line frame in ISE, it executes whitout giving any error.

I also tried removing items with a foreach{xxx.Items.Remove()}, setting Items to $null, none worked.

If someone has an idea, he's welcome ! (thanks)

DDF

Answer (score 0):

If the breakpoint is allowing you to manually enter the command, it would appear that maybe this is a timing issue?

I would try using the Start-Sleep powershell command before calling clear and see if that solves it.

```
Start-Sleep -s 10
```

The above command would cause the program to sleep for 10 seconds.

Reference 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177002.aspx

Comment: No, no luck ! I thought about this but I know that it isn't a timeout problem because actually, I have 2 ComboBoxes in my code. When I stopped on the first one with the breakpoint, I ran the code for the second one and the error was thrown... sorry I didn't put the complete code because because it's useless. But thanks for the suggestion !

Answer (score 0):

I've just run your code and didn't get any errors clicking Search button many times. Maybe there's an issue with the user contex.

Try to run powershell with default environment:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile
```

And then your script:

```
PS> D:\WorkingDir\PS\fa.ps1
```

Comment: Which Powershell version you use? ($PSVersionTable). Can you try on another machine?

Comment: Gives me the same error on another machine. I just changed the code in the original post. You need to edit the "where-object" commands to test it on your side. (lines 73, 89, 133, 156 & 180)

Comment: I was trying on version 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using the [`ItemsSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the ComboBox. If you don't try to `Clear()` it or reset it to `@()`, it works great. Thanks for your help !